# Enable/Disable Header Button on Picker Tap

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native. I have used a button in my header and a picker for my project. Initially I have disabled by button, but I want it to enable on tapping the Picker. Below is my code.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerRight: (
      <View 
        <Button
          disabled = {true}
          title="Save"

        />
      </View>
    )
  });

render(){
return(
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.changedVal}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.pickerActivity(itemValue)}>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use navigation params like the title management here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerRight: (
      <View 
        <Button
          disabled = {navigation.getParams('isButtonDisable', true)}
          title="Save"

        />
      </View>
    )
  });

pickerActivity = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    if(itemValue === 'js') {
        this.props.navigation.setParams('isButtonDisable', false);
    } else {
        this.props.navigation.setParams('isButtonDisable', true);
    }
}

render(){
return(
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.changedVal}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
    onValueChange={this.pickerActivity}>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
  )
}
```